# Can I use WCF on Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I am about to start a project which consumes third party web services. Because of a legacy system, I am told that I can only use Visual Studio 2005/.NET 2.0. (Though I would have preferred Visual Studio 2008 on .NET 3.5)

My understanding is that WCF was released with .NET 3.0. So is there any possibility to use WCF on Visual Studio 2005 by using just the WCF assemblies of .NET 3.0? I will then try to convince them that it is just like using external framework which doesn't disturb anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read here the steps how to setup **WCF in VS 2005**

http://blogs.msdn.com/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx

or

Download **WCF templates for VS 2005**

http://blog.stevienova.com/2007/02/25/net-30-wpfwcf-templates-for-vs2005/

and install **.net framework 3.0**

Here are some useful links for **WCF Extensions** and for other useful information.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b297421e-5030-47e2-96e1-6d1d9920c9c7/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1331127.aspx

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://www.zdnet.co.uk/downloads/developer-tools/2007/08/21/the-visual-studio-2005-extensions-fornet-framework-30-wcf-and-wpf-november-2006-ctp-3-39328336/

I hope this helps!